# Crunchbang as an optimal OS?

Tags: linux, distributions, crunchbang

I have a small netbook that I've been using for all of my learning to program/learning to *nix needs. It is pretty underpowered (1gb RAM, 1.66hz processor) and has a dire battery life (under an hour really) as I got it for free from a friend. The Windows OS on it was slowing it down so much, and as they were giving it to me, I formatted and installed Crunchbang over the top.

I'd never used [Crunchbang](http://crunchbang.org/about/) before, but I have now become a big fan. It's quite confusing for me still, having no menu bar or anything, and having to manually edit the entries in the right-click menu if I want to add anything to it, but it is pretty speedy, and seems really quite nice to use.

However, I'll soon be buying myself a new small netbook, with the same specs, but one with a much better battery life (apparently just under 8 hours in actual tests, with WiFi on and running Windows... two things I will not be doing), and was wondering whether or not Crunchbang would be a good choice of OS to install on it again?

I know that 'which OS is better' makes for a very poor question, but I hope that mine is more specific, namely **is Crunchbang good for underpowered systems, and will it ever restrict my ability to do things that I might want to do when it comes to programming/delving further into the workings of computer systems? If so, what is a good alternative? Or is it simply a matter of taste?**

Comment: There is no "optimal" but Crunchbang seems to be a decent choice (I'm loading onto a VM right now because you got me curious). It shouldn't limit you in any way that I can think of. A comparable distro would be Lubuntu, but that is almost certainly a matter of taste.

Comment: Crunchbang is nice but I recommend Archlinux + openbox/dwm which is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run Crunchbang 10 on a 10 inch netbook with an AMD C60 CPU. Crunchbang is quite lightweight: On a Netbook, the limitations will be mostly on the hardware side.

Example: Working on the command line or in a simple text editor, the CPU runs at about 5%. Recording a live audio stream via Internet or using a browser like Firefox will brings the CPU up to 50-60%.

As it is the closest to Debian I am able to run properly at the moment [I really don't have the knowledge to fix the issues now] I am very very happy with it.

There are enough flamewars about which GUI to use – and I don't care much: I made the experience that KDE and GNOME are a bit heavy for a Netbook. I really liked using Mint Debian Edition with XFCE running, from where I switched to the even – at least it felt so – lighter LXDE Desktop.
Every Desktop is a different approach to get stuff done. Basically: Pizza or Pasta? whatever one prefers at the moment. But as mentioned above: KDE is a bit heavy for a Netbook. I am sure there are a thousand ways to fix this, but I really love the minimalism of OpenBox as it is implemented in Crunchbang.

And then there is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution to give one a nice first overview.

Comment: thank you, nice to hear about your experiences with it! also, shall have a browse through that list :)

Comment: +1 well stated, agnostic response (even though this question will likely be closed soon for being opinion-ish)

Comment: The user asks for experience with a certain lightweight Distro AND alternatives. Some Desktops and Distros are more suitable for Netbooks than others. There is a reason these distros exist are are customized. 'Opinionish' borders flame, true. But facts like "This takes up more RAM than that" is measurable and must be taken into account if there aren't slots free for upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You ask: " . . . [I]s Crunchbang good for underpowered systems . . ."?

Yes.

" . . . [W]ill it ever restrict my ability to do things that I might want to do when it comes to programming/delving further into the workings of computer systems?"

No.

"If so, what is a good alternative? Or is it simply a matter of taste?"

It is a matter of taste. There's about 320 active distros out there, according to DistroWatch.com, so clearly you have alternatives. What's key is that you find something that works for you. CrunchBang works for me on a variety of levels, which is why I have been using it as a daily distro for close to two years -- it's based on Debian, the forums are filled with knowledgeable and friendly folks and CrunchBang is focused on being a good day-to-day distro rather than being at the top of the list.

Give it a try -- if it works for you, excellent. If not, find the one that does.